# Implementing ls -R command in linux

Tags: c, linux, recursion

I want to know how `ls -R` implemented in C language.
Is it use the  recursion algorithm?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I'm afraid recursion brings about stack overflow.

Comment: Recursing in your case might cause stack - overflow, if you do not skip the directories `.` and `..`

Comment: There is no single *recursion* algorithm. But some algorithms (actually, set of functions) may be [co-]*recursive* and *recursion* is a feature of such algorithms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"ls" (at least the implementations that I know of) use `fts_open`, `fts_read` ... to traverse a file hierarchy. These are "non-recursive" methods which maintain a list of the visited directories internally.

Use "man fts_read" or http://linux.die.net/man/3/fts_read to get more information about these functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the relevant code-block

```
<includes...>
int f_recursive;        /* ls subdirectories also */
while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "1ABCFLRSTWabcdfghiklmnopqrstuwx")) != -1) {
    switch (ch) {
.
.
.
.
case 'R':
    f_recursive = 1;
    break;
```

Later, the directory listing is done recursively because of the above **int** flag.

**[See source here.](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/bin/ls/ls.c?rev=1.67&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup)**

Recursing in your case might cause stackoverflow, **if** you do not skip the directories `.` and `..`.

It doesn't seem like any recursion is done within `ls.c` though. It uses **[fts-functions](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fts.3.html)**, like fts_children to traverse the heirarchies. You could use the same.

Comment: The variable is called `f_recursive`, but the implementation is not recursive: the `traverse()` function (from the linked source) does not call itself recursively.

Comment: @MartinR I hadn't looked in detail. Will update answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinR, [fts_children](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/fts.3.html) seems to do all the work, fetching the listing, so I guess there isn't any recursion within `ls.c` but within, fts, there is.

Comment: I am quite sure that fts does not use recursion internally, but I had written that already in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness, ls is part of GNU coreutils: www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple linux `ls -R` implementation in C. It gives coloured output similar to `ls`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#define GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define WHITE   "\x1b[37m"

void Usage() {
    fprintf(stderr, "\nUsage: exec [OPTION]... [DIR]...\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "List DIR's (directory) contents\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "\nOptions\n-R\tlist subdirectories recursively\n");
    return;
}

void RecDir(char *path, int flag) {
    DIR *dp = opendir(path);
    if(!dp) {
        perror(path);
        return;
    }
    struct dirent *ep;
    char newdir[512];
    printf(BLUE "\n%s :\n" WHITE, path);
    while((ep = readdir(dp)))
        if(strncmp(ep->d_name, ".", 1))
            printf(GREEN "\t%s\n" WHITE, ep->d_name);
    closedir(dp);
    dp = opendir(path);
    while((ep = readdir(dp))) if(strncmp(ep->d_name, ".", 1)) {
        if(flag && ep->d_type == 4) {
            sprintf(newdir, "%s/%s", path, ep->d_name);
            RecDir(newdir, 1);
        }
    }
    closedir(dp);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    switch(argc) {
    case 2:
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-R") == 0) Usage();
        else RecDir(argv[1], 0);
        break;
    case 3:
        if(strcmp(argv[1], "-R") == 0) RecDir(argv[2], 1);
        else Usage();
        break;
    default: Usage();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help you.

```
 void listDir(char *dirName)
 {
     DIR* dir;
     struct dirent *dirEntry;
     struct stat inode;
     char name[1000];
     dir = opendir(dirName);
     if (dir == 0) {
        perror ("Eroare deschidere fisier");
        exit(1);
     }
     while ((dirEntry=readdir(dir)) != 0) {
        sprintf(name,"%s/%s",dirName,dirEntry->d_name); 
        lstat (name, &inode);

        // test the type of file
        if (S_ISDIR(inode.st_mode))
           printf("dir ");
        else if (S_ISREG(inode.st_mode))
           printf ("fis ");
        else
          if (S_ISLNK(inode.st_mode))
            printf ("lnk ");
        else;
          printf(" %s\n", dirEntry->d_name);
  }
```